# Rotten Rotten Tomatoes

Tags: facebook

How does this new "Instant Personalization" Facebook feature work? It seems like a terrible idea to me. But if Rotten Tomatoes can use it, then can I too? Or is it only available to certain special partners?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which Facebook API can I use to get Foursquare like signup behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584360/which-facebook-api-can-i-use-to-get-foursquare-like-signup-behavior)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instant personalization is only available to select partners. For everyone else, the normal OAuth authorization and permissions are going to have be used.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't find any references to it on the Facebook developer website so wasn't sure. Although I'm not a big fan of it, I don't want to be at a competitive disadvantage if others are using it.